# How to Pop all items from a BST without destroying the tree?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

So i was trying to create a method that return's me all the nodes of a binary search tree without deleting them. I want to let my data structure untouched.
But i can't find a way to do it!

The only think a have succeed at was to create a pop method that return's the root (cloned) of the bst and after that delete's it. The code is this:

```
    def pop(self):

    #Empty tree.
    if self.root == None:
        return None

    #Copy the root.
    return_node = self.root.clone()

    #Find MAX Node.
    if self.root.left != None:

        #Starting node.
        MAX = self.root.left

        #Find max node.
        while MAX.right != None:
            MAX = MAX.right

        #Swap data with root.
        self.root.swap_data(MAX)

        #Destroy max node.
        MAX.destroy()



    #Find MIN Node.
    elif self.root.right != None:

        #Starting node.
        MIN = self.root.right

        #Find max node.
        while MIN.left != None:
            MIN = MIN.left

        #Swap data with root.
        self.root.swap_data(MIN)

        #Destroy max node.
        MIN.destroy()


    #Else set root to none.
    else:
        self.root = None



    #Return the poped node.
    self.size -= 1
    return return_node
```

So this code works like a charm with this loop:

```
node = tree.pop()

while node != None:
    #Do something with current node

    node = tree.pop() #Keep moving.
```

but the problem is that the tree will finally be destroyed.

After that i thought that a traversal method could do the trick but
i couldn't succeed.

```
def preorder(self, root):

    if root == None:
        return

    #Do something here.
    #But how am i going to return all the nodes
    #Using this traversal method?

    self.preorder(root.left)
    self.preorder(root.right)
```

So is there a way to get all the items from a binary search tree
without destroying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without code that implements your BST and without **how you want the result to look like**.

The pop method you provided is incorrect. During node removal, 3 cases are possible:

1. Curent node has no right child node -- in that case we need to move left to current
2. Current node has only right child node without left subchild -- we move right to current
3. Current node has right child with left subclild -- need to move left**most** of right child to current

Seems you're reinventing the wheel, but there's almost iconic implementation of BST in Python [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577540-python-binary-search-tree/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually you are wrong. Pop doesn't work like a remove method.
There are only two possibilities. Max and Min nodes will be leafs or
they will have only one child. There is no way that they will have more
than one child because my algorithm searches for max or min node until max.right or min.left is None.